# How to monkey patch new control structures in Scala?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to monkey-patch a new control structure in Scala? Basically I want to define a couple of control structures, such as the following unless method, and have them accessible anywhere in my project.

```
def unless(condition: => Boolean)(body: => Unit):Unit = if(!condition) body
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot *monkey patch*, which changes objects that already exist.  However, you can write an *implicit conversion* that acts the same way (and is arguably safer) in most cases.

First of all, with `unless` as written, you don't need it to be a method of every class.  Just stick it in some object and import.

```
object Utility {
  def unless(condition: => Boolean)(body: => Unit):Unit = if(!condition) body
}

import Utility._
```

But sometimes you *do* want it to act like a method on a class.  For example, I often write

```
option.map(x => f(x)).getOrElse(default)
```

which could be more compactly written as a fold:

```
option.fold(default)(x => f(x))
```

except that `Option` doesn't have fold.  So I:

```
class OptionWrapper[A](o: Option[A]) {
  def fold[Z](default: => Z)(action: A => Z) = o.map(action).getOrElse(default)
}
implicit def option_has_utility[A](o: Option[A]) = new OptionWrapper(o)
```

(this is called the "pimp my library" pattern).  Now I can use fold to my heart's content, since any time there is an option and I call the `fold` method, the compiler realizes that there is no `fold` method and looks around for any way it can convert the class into something that does have a `fold`.  There is such a method, and the new class does to the existing option exactly what you would want from a `fold` method on the class itself.

Comment: Regarding "arguably safer", let's argue. How is an implicit conversion any safer than monkey patching? It still allows objects to use methods that the original class did not have available.

Comment: @DanBurton why don't you ask it as a question?

Comment: @Dan Burton - With monkey patching, you can have a mix of objects some of which have a method and some of which don't; this raises problems where you expect an object to have a method but it hasn't been patched in (or the wrong version has been patched in).  With implicit conversions, you have compile-time type safety: the classes are guaranteed to have the methods they have, and the conversions are guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2):

If all your classes are under a single package (and remember packages [can be nested](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/package-clauses/packageclauses.html) in Scala!), you can place your definitions in a [`package object`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html).